# Merging tables in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have 2 web sites and i am sending all the GA data into Big Query. Since Big Query would create different tables for each site, i would like to merge them into one. Also  i would like to create a record to indicate the site's name so that site A and Site B data won't be mixed.

Is this possible? I have tried union, it works fine but just the i am not able to differentiate the data between site a and site b.

Appreciated 
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Assuming schemas identical:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT *, 'siteA' AS site FROM TableA),
(SELECT *, 'siteB' AS site FROM TableB)
```

you should use [ ] when using fully qualified table name  - project:dataset.table

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT *, 'siteA' AS site FROM [ga:123.ga_sessions_20160502]), 
(SELECT *, 'siteB' AS site FROM [ga:456.ga_sessions_20160501])
```

Comment: yes schemas are identical. but not able to run your query. SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT *, 'siteA' AS site FROM ga:123.ga_sessions_20160502),
(SELECT *, 'siteB' AS site FROM ga:456.ga_sessions_20160501)@Mikhail Berlyant

Comment: Error: Encountered " "-" "- "" at line 2, column 36. Was expecting: ")" ...
RUN QUERY

Comment: Is there a way to exclude duplicate records if we use this methods to fetch data from different tables of same structure?

Comment: i think so. you should post your question though so we can answer it